# Is there a way to inspect a clousure in Javascript (or local variables)

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like:

```
function example(name){
  var age = 0;
  var started = false;
  var start = function(){
    started = true;
  }
  this.forward = function(){
    age++;
  }
  console.log( SOMECODE );
}

example('boby');
```

I expect in `SOMECODE` something that print some similar to:

```
name: "boby"
age: 0
started: false
start: [Function]
forward: [Function]
```

I like to write something like:

```
function inspect(locals){
  for(var name in locals){
    console.log(name, ':', locals[name]);
  }
}

console.log(inspect(example.locals));
// or
console.log(inspect(example.stack[-1].locals));
// or
console.log(inspect(example.clousure));
```

My aim is to program automatized tools for debuging inside my programs, or write general prupouse logs. Or print call stack with values of local variables.

Comment: There is no closure involved here. All the variables you are trying to access are in the same scope

Comment: First your example have to closure and second, `this.forward = function () {...}` should be right.

Comment: You are write. I write more code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Example(name) {
  // define `init` function
  var obj = {};
  this.init = function (name) {
    // set `this` properties , values
    var name = name;
    var age = 0;
    var started = false;

    var start = function start() {
      started = true;
    }
    var forward = function forward() {
      age++;
    }
    this.forward = forward;
    
      obj[name] = name;
      obj[age] = age;
      obj["started"] = started;
      obj["start"] = start;
      obj["forward"] = forward;

    return this
    // this.start();
    // this.forward()
  }
  // call `this.init`
  var res = this.init(name);
  console.log( obj );
}

var example = new Example("boby");
console.log(example);
```

---

Comment: Yes, but in your code the private variables (var age) become public (this.age). Private in [crockfors](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html) sense

Comment: @EmilioPlatzer _"Yes, but in your code the private variables (var age) become public (this.age). Private in crockfors sense"_ Not appear indicated at Question that `age` should remain "private" ?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry about don't be clear. I want remain untouched all the lines up to this.forward definition.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using *breakpoints* in the Chrome dev tools, it is easy.

First, open up the dev tools and click on the Sources tab. Find the Javascript file that contains the code you wish to inspect and select it. The file's contents will appear in the window to the right.

Next, click on one of the line numbers in the left column to insert a breakpoint. Using your code above, try somewhere around ~line 10  (well, anywhere in the closure would work as well). Re-load the page and when the breakpoint is reached, you'll be able to inspect the values of the various variables in the "Scope" window, below.

Comment: I want something programaticaly

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following. Here I am creating a new instance of example(myExample). So the this keyword inside the function will refer to myExample(or any other instance that invokes example) so you can set properties and also console.log

https://jsfiddle.net/w46ec5eb/1/

```
function example(name){
  this.age = 0;
  this.started = false;
  this.start = function(){
    this.started = true;
  };
  this.forward = function(){
    this.age++;
  };
  console.log(this );
}

var myExample = new example('boby');
myExample.start();
myExample.forward();
console.log(myExample);
```